# How to use Windows headset as Android call headset

Tags: headset

I have a Windows PC with USB headset. I want to connect it to Android phone, so I can make calls using my computer's headset. Can I do so with usb, bluetooth, minijack or lan?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is definitely possible - but not without special connective devices. You can actually use a variety off available connectors to extend comopatibility to the device, such as USB to 3.0 headphone adapter, and if your device will support the connection type, you could also use the MICROusb to USB 2\3.0 adapters.

Do a search online for one of the above mentioned devices, and learn more about them and your phones compatibility. You may also purchase of from almost any online electronic supply chains, as well as finding information regarding where to purchase one of the adapters locally.

Comment: Saying it's possible may provide some encouragement, but it isn't actually a solution.  Can you edit the answer to elaborate on how to accomplish that?  If the question is too ambiguous to answer specifically, that's a sign that it's too broad, and those questions are very hard to answer well.  With a little more rep, you will be able to post helpful hints and suggestions of directions to pursue as a comment.  Thanks.

Comment: Couple you provide me with a little guidance on how to best do this? I understand what you mean, but I am not quite sure how I could edit the current answer to contain any more specific steps on accomplishing what the questions asks. (For example, I have provided all the ways by which this could be accomplished, along with information regarding how to find the best route.)  I appreciate the feedback, I am just unsure about how exactly to utilize it.

Comment: Answers are better is they're "actionable", or at least specific enough that the reader can see what you're describing and how to adapt it to their case.  So a better answer would be to give a specific example, even if it isn't a precise fit.  (cont'd)

Comment: In addition to the general guidance, illustrate an example case.  Maybe a diagram and pictures of the components used for that case (whatever's needed to be clear and unambiguous).  Then the reader can find the specific adapters for their hardware.  On an ambiguous question, though, you can easily put in a lot of work only to find out that it doesn't address what the question's author was thinking about.  It's better to get clarification from the author first.